# how to make UIView work as an scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

I need some serious help on this problem of mine where I need to work a `UIView` as an `ScrollView`. Below uploaded picture will clear all the doubts.

[image]

I have taken four buttons along with a `UIView` below them along with 4 container views which I have placed one above the other so as to work along with the four buttons.. What I want now is to work `UIView` as an `ScrollView`. Whenever I click any button, the View moves forward as well as the it changes the container view. And respective container view shows whenever I click a button.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: - (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    self.title=@"LOGIN";
    [_ScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)Register:(id)sender {
    self.title=@"REGISTER";
    [_ScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_login.frame.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
}
             This code is from my other project...in that project i have used 2 containers along with a scroll view and above that 2buttons along with a UIView. Same logic I am trying to apply in here.But its not happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi better you can use UIScrollView instead of UIView like:

```
//Declare it 
NSMutableArray * buttonArray
int selectedIndex;


-(void)setUpSegmentBar {

    NSArray * namesOfMenus =@[@"Button1",@"Button2",@"Button3",@"Button4",@"Button5"];

    // Scrollview added on storyBoard
    myScrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    CGFloat scrollWidth = 0.f;

   buttonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for ( int j=0; j<namesOfMenus.count; j++)
    {
        NSString * name =[namesOfMenus objectAtIndex:j];
        CGSize size = [name sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_button]}];

        CGSize textSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
        CGFloat strikeWidth;

        if (iPAD) {
            strikeWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/5.5;
        }else{
            strikeWidth = textSize.width;
        }
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(scrollWidth, 0,strikeWidth+20, 40);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setTag:j];
        button.frame = frame;
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        button.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // ScrollWidth As per Button Width
        scrollWidth= scrollWidth+strikeWidth+20;

        // to Check Which Button Is Selected.
        if (j==selectedIndex) {
            // If Selected Do UI Changes
            button.backgroundColor=segment_selected_Color ;
            [button setTitleColor:segment_disselected_Color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addLayerAndCornerRadius:0 AndWidth:1 AndColor:segment_disselected_Color];
            [button addShaddow];
            if (iPhone6||iPhone6plus) {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }else {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }
        }else {
            // Other Buttons
            [button addLayerAndCornerRadius:0 AndWidth:1 AndColor:segment_disselected_Color];
            button.backgroundColor=segment_disselected_Color;
            [button setTitleColor:segment_selected_Color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            if (iPhone6||iPhone6plus) {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }else{
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }
        }
        // Add Buttons in Array
        [buttonArray addObject:button];
        // Add button on Scroll View
        [myScrollView addSubview:button];

    }
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 30.f);
    myScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    myScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    [myScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [myScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    return myScrollView;

}
```

And For Handeling button action.

```
-(void)buttonEvent:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSInteger index= sender.tag;
    selectedIndex= (int) index;

    for(int i=0;i<buttonArray.count;i++)
    {
        UIButton * button =(UIButton*)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i==selectedIndex) {
            [button addLayerAndCornerRadius:0 AndWidth:1 AndColor:segment_disselected_Color];
            button.backgroundColor=segment_selected_Color ;
            [button setTitleColor:segment_disselected_Color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addShaddow];
            if (iPhone6||iPhone6plus) {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }else {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }
        }else {
            button.backgroundColor=segment_disselected_Color;
            [button addLayerAndCornerRadius:0 AndWidth:1 AndColor:segment_disselected_Color];
            [button setTitleColor:segment_selected_Color forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            if (iPhone6||iPhone6plus) {
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }else{
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font_bold size:font_size_normal_regular];
            }
        }
    }

    CGRect frame1 = myScrollView.frame;
    UIButton * bt=(UIButton*)[buttonArray objectAtIndex:index];
    frame1 =bt.frame ;
// By using it button will scroll and show properly
    [myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame1 animated:YES];
    [self setupTableAfterClick];
}
```

Comment: By using your code how can I change ContainerView??

Comment: Yes, You have to use scroll view as a base view and then bycalling setupSegment you add buttons on scrollview. If you want to do custumization on cantainer then do on scrollview and wanna do custumization on segment do change on button.