# How to make Horizontal scrollView and some buttons in it (programming)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

sorry,I have a problem.I don't use storyBoard.

I want to make a view like this.
[photo by terenceLuffy/AppStoreStyleHorizontalScrollView](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/981c03a8c109b8649e54a154d6478b44c9b44e89/68747470733a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f7875736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f752f39313637353332332f7468756d626f6f6b72312e676966)

but I try to do this.
Finlly,scrollView just show last button like this.
[image]

This is code:

```
var scView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
var buttonPadding:CGFloat = 10
var xOffset:CGFloat = 10


scView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


func viewDidLoad() {

for i in 0 ... 10 {

    let button = UIButton()

    button.tag = i
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTouch), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 70, height: 30)

    xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width
    scView.addSubview(button)


}

scView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scView.frame.height)

}
```

please help me.
Thanks all!

Comment: Why not UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling ???

Comment: can you show how you add UIScrollView to your view?

Comment: view.addSubview(scView)

Comment: seems your code does not have any issue. except you are calling it in view did load. please try my answer and let me know if any issue

Comment: i have tried your code and it works perfectly, maybe you have other methods that change offset position of uiscrollview or something?

Comment: Please Check This , I wrote Answer there but its in ObjC. You can use same logic in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518215/how-to-make-uiview-work-as-an-scrollview/38518744#38518744

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried your code and changed it a bit. It works as expected, unless you have something other going on:

```
var scView:UIScrollView!
let buttonPadding:CGFloat = 10
var xOffset:CGFloat = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: view.bounds.width, height: 50))
    view.addSubview(scView)

    scView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    scView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    for i in 0 ... 10 {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTouch), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 70, height: 30)

        xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width
        scView.addSubview(button)


    }

    scView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scView.frame.height)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways of achieving it :) One the hard way using scrollView and calculating offset and setting views programmatically on ScrollView as subView else use **CollectionView**

**Step 1:**

Add a UICollectionView to storyboard, set the height of collectionView to match your requirement :)

[image]

**Step 2**

Create a cell, size of which depends on your requirement. I have created a cell with background colour orange/pink. Added a label on it to show your number.

[image]

**Step 3:**

Set the reusable cell identifier to the cell and set its class as well :)

[image]

[image]

**Step 4 :**

Set collectionView scroll direction to horizontal :)

[image]

**Step 5:**

Now implement collectionView delegates and data source methods :)

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.myLabel.text = "ABCD"
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Thats all :)

**Final O/P**

[image]

Look at collectionView with cell ABCD :D

**Additional Info**

If you are dragging a collectionView on UIViewController, you might see that the collectionView leaves a gap at the top which you can solve by unchecking Adjust ScrollView Insets of ViewController :)

[image]

Comment: thanks,but i just want to use scrollView to show my view.

Answer (score 3):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageStrings:[String] = []
     var myScrollView:UIScrollView!


    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIImageView!



    var scrollWidth : CGFloat = 320
    let scrollHeight : CGFloat = 100
    let thumbNailWidth : CGFloat = 80
    let thumbNailHeight : CGFloat = 80
    let padding: CGFloat = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageStrings = ["image01","image02","image03","image04","image05","image06","image07","image08"]

        scrollWidth = self.view.frame.width

        //setup scrollView
        myScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.height - scrollHeight, scrollWidth, scrollHeight))

        //setup content size for scroll view
        let contentSizeWidth:CGFloat = (thumbNailWidth + padding) * (CGFloat(imageStrings.count))
        let contentSize = CGSize(width: contentSizeWidth ,height: thumbNailHeight)

        myScrollView.contentSize = contentSize
        myScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth


        for(index,value) in enumerate(imageStrings) {
            var button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as! UIButton
            //calculate x for uibutton
            var xButton = CGFloat(padding * (CGFloat(index) + 1) + (CGFloat(index) * thumbNailWidth))
            button.frame = CGRectMake(xButton,padding, thumbNailWidth, thumbNailHeight)
            button.tag = index

            let image = UIImage(named:value)
            button.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changeImage:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            myScrollView.addSubview(button)
        }
        previewView.image = UIImage(named: imageStrings[0])
        self.view.addSubview(myScrollView)
    }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func changeImage(sender:UIButton){
        let name = imageStrings[sender.tag]
        previewView.image = UIImage(named: name)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy with minimal use of storyboard. You can avoid that rather easily. All you need are:

1. Scroll view
2. Horizontal stack view
3. Set the constraints of the above as shown in the project
4. A number of buttons - as many view controllers that need to be displayed.
5. A container view - this will be the view that will hold the active view controller.

Please refer to this project for some sample code:
https://github.com/equitronix/horizontalScrollMenu

Answer (score 0):

```
    //make that variable gloabl
   let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    var arrMmenu :  NSMutableArray = []
    var  selectedIndex : Int = 0
     @IBOutlet weak var btnScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var lineArray : NSMutableArray = []
    var buttonArray : NSMutableArray = []
```

//Call buttonCreated()

```
  //MARK:- Create an Horizontral LayOut
func buttonCreated()
{

    btnScrollView.contentSize.width = 0
 namesOfMenu = ["GMC","GPA","GTL"]
    var scrollwidth: CGFloat = 10.0

    for j in 0..<namesOfMenu.count
    {
        let name = namesOfMenu[j] as! String
        let size : CGSize? = name.size(withAttributes : [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)])


        let textsize = CGSize(width : CGFloat(ceilf(Float(size!.width))), height : CGFloat(ceilf(Float(size!.height))))

        var strikwidth : CGFloat = textsize.width
        strikwidth = textsize.width + 30
        let frame = CGRect(x: scrollwidth , y : CGFloat(7),width :CGFloat(strikwidth + 20) , height :CGFloat(20))
        let frameLine = CGRect(x: scrollwidth , y : CGFloat(30),width :CGFloat(strikwidth + 20) , height :CGFloat(2))
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        let line = UIView()
        line.frame = frameLine
        button.tag = j
        view.tag = j
        button.frame = frame
        line .backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonEvent(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle(name, for : .normal)
        scrollwidth = scrollwidth + strikwidth + 30
        let strofMenu = namesOfMenu[selectedIndex] as! String

        if (j == selectedIndex)
        {

            if(strofMenu == "GMC")
            {
                // apicall()
            }

            line.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3174C7")
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            button.setTitleColor(hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3174C7"), for: UIControlState.normal)


        }else
        {
            line.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            button.setTitleColor(MyConstant.Color.dark_gray_shade, for: UIControlState.normal)

        }
        button.titleLabel?.font =  MyConstant.fontApp.Regular

        buttonArray.add(button)

        lineArray.add(line)

        btnScrollView.addSubview(button)

        btnScrollView.addSubview(line)

    }

    btnScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width : CGFloat(scrollwidth), height :  CGFloat(40.0))

    btnScrollView.isPagingEnabled = false

    btnScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    btnScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}

//MARK:- Button Event

@objc func buttonEvent(_ sender : UIButton)

{

    let index = sender.tag

    selectedIndex = index

    let getRepoName = namesOfMenu[index] as! String

    print(getRepoName)


    for i in 0..<buttonArray.count

    {

        let buttonone : UIButton = (buttonArray[i] as! UIButton)

        let line : UIView  = (lineArray[i]) as! UIView

        if i == selectedIndex
        {
            buttonone.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            line.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3174C7")

            buttonone.setTitleColor(hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#3174C7"), for: .normal)
            //
            //                if(getRepoName == "GMC")
            //                {
            //                    clickedCellIndexes.add(0)
            //
            //                    arrmutablefordata.removeAllObjects()
            //                    tblhome.reloadData()
            //                    apicall()
            //                }


            //buttonone.titleLabel
        }else
        {
            buttonone.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            line.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            buttonone.setTitleColor(MyConstant.Color.dark_gray_shade, for: .normal)

        }





    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Doing it from the storyboard using scroll view and stack views makes this a very simple solution. Along with a bunch of sub view controllers and transitions. I have posted sample code on GitHub. Please take a look here:

https://github.com/equitronix/horizontalScrollMenu

Let me know if this works.