# Implement a horizontal Scroll View in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, swift4.2

I want to create this type of view (a `ChipView`) with horizontal scrolling list in Swift:

[image: this type UIView]

I want to create with scroll with applied filter display.

Comment: Have you tried using a horizontal `UIScrollView`? See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279356/how-to-make-horizontal-scrollview-and-some-buttons-in-it-programming).

Comment: You can create this view using UICollectionView

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately this is not a design or code writing service. Please provide the code you've tried so far.